# Get the services cases in Power BI from Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, dynamics-crm-online

I have a Dynamics CRM Online instance and manage different service cases, I associate the cases in the client fields sometime with an account or with a contact.

I install the Dynamics CRM Online Service content pack in Power BI and I look in the cases that I can only see the name of the contact (customers) and I can not see the name of the account in cases associate with it.

[image: Only show the contacts]

In Power BI if I create a table of cases and associate with the name of the account It says me that 'Can't display the visual'.

So later I create a new report in Power BI desktop and connect with the REST endpoint, then in the navigator windows I don't see the cases entity, and can't find something related

How can I see the cases with customers and cases with accounts associated

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the relationships and attributes for each entities,
Entity: Case 
  CaseId, AccountId (lookup), CustomerId (lookup)
Account
  AccountId
Customer
  CustomerId

If you are using PBI Desktop - you can import(load) the data and join three entities like this,
Case with Account -> Case_Accounts
Case with Customer -> Case_Customers
Case_Accounts with Case_Customers

Create your matrix or table or chart based on your need.